Google sheets sum with condition
I am attempting to sum a series of cells, most of which have a number value, but some have a literal such as 'X' or 'U or are blank, for example

4
U
2
2
X
2
4


3

I would like to sum the column, and treat 'X' and 'U' as zero and ignore blanks.
I have attempted several functions that chatgpt has suggested, all of which result in either #value or #error and one of them resulted in #ref
These are some of the functions I've been suggested by chatgpt:
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(V3:V263), V3:V263, IF(V3:V263="X", 0, IF(V3:V263="U", 0, VALUE(V3:V263)))))=SUM(IF(V3:V263="X", 0, IF(V3:V263="U", 0, V3:V263)))=SUMIF (V3:V263, ISNUMBER(V3:V363), V3:V263),
After pointing out the #value and #error result to chatgpt, it suggested I create a new column and include this function into each cell, and then sum on the new column
=IF(ISNUMBER(V3), V3, IF(V3="X", 0, IF(V3="U", 0, VALUE(V3))))
But I am reluctant to include a new column. The sheet is large and unwieldy as it is. Any suggestions.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

column V, row 266 in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AGsSsUoomMY6YRdykv-qxYQsdERSb4y2/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108117270463343576000&rtpof=true&sd=true

Tags should be about what is being asked, not what was mentioned. In this case, the fact that you used ChatGPT, while it is part of your research efforts, is not about what is being asked.

So what is the ideal expected output over there?!

Regarding demo spreadsheet, while a link to a demo spreadsheet might make things easier for some, please bear in mind that questions on this site should be self-contained. In other words,  all the relevant details, like the relevant spreadsheet settings and structure, sample input data and expected results, should be included in the question, whenever possible, as text.

I would like to sum the column, from V3 to V266, and treat 'X' and 'U' as zero and ignore blanks. For example, the sum for the sample in my original post would be 17.

so just use =sum(V3:V263) and you'll get 1081 as the output

Is the 'X' and 'U' treated like a zero with your suggestion?

sum function ignores text and blanks by default unless you have a specific reason why you wish to explicitly consider them as zero?!

Suggestion
If you are attempting to calculate the sum of several cells, where you need to specifically treat some cells that contain the non-numeric characters 'X' or 'U' as 0 and simply ignore blank cells, you may want to try this method using the MAP and REGEXMATCH functions:
=SUM(MAP(V3:V263, LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(IF(REGEXMATCH(x, "U|X"), 0, x),x))))

Demo

References

Google Sheet IFERROR function


I guess the easiest option would be:
=SUMIF(V3:V300,”>0”)

